# Laravel 5.8 websocket won't fire an event

Tags: laravel, websocket

I followed this tutorial https://christoph-rumpel.com/2020/11/laravel-real-time-notifications and everything works great until i had to run php command to fire an event.

- **Laravel**: 5.8
- **Pusher**: ~4.0
- **HestiaCP**: apache2 + nginx reverse proxy
- **php.ini**: no disabled function

This is my conf:

**.env**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
PUSHER_APP_ID=local
PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=local
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT=/home/admin/web/ssl/mysite.app.crt
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK=/home/admin/web/ssl/mysite.app.key

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

**broadcasting.php**

```
 'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'useTLS' => true,
            'scheme' => 'https://',
            'encrypted' => true,
            'curl_options' => [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    encrypted: true,
    wsHost: 'mysite.app', // i didn't miss this
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
});
```

**websockets.php**

```
'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'enable_client_messages' => true,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
],
```

**RealTimeMessage.php ( event )**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class RealTimeMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public string $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(string $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return  new Channel('events');
    }
}
```

**frontend**

```
Echo.channel('events')
    .listen('RealTimeMessage', (e) => console.log('RealTimeMessage: ' + e.message));
```

**Network Tab**

[image]

Console log is empty when I fire an event..

On: `/laravel-websockets` I successfully connect and also successfully listen for event as you can see here:

[image: https://prnt.sc/pcK62whMwz16]

but I can't fire an event.

I made function `/broadcast` where I fire an event:

```
Route::get('/broadcast', function(){
  event(new App\Events\RealTimeMessage('Hello World'));
});
```

Queue returns this:

[image]

Tinker returns this:

[image]

`BroadcastOn` function is firing, I made simple query inside to make a new record in database, and its working, so its calling.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Did you really try to run on a Laravel 5.8 and follow tutorial for 8?

Comment: For Laravel under 6, when you see `MIX` variable, then in your `.env` must start with `MIX`. So this is wrong `PUSHER_APP_KEY ` => `MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY`

Comment: I forgot to add that, I edited my question.

Comment: I used packages and dependencies for my Laravel version, not for 8. Also there is ton of other tutorials that I watched and been googling for like 5 days.. I am sure it's server problem, not an configuration. I think I figure it and the solution is maybe to allow connections and packets for :6001 in nginx (reverse proxy).

Comment: I have same issue did you find any solution for it????